# How receive json object from client into a php 2D array at server?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I want to fill a 2D array in php from a JSON object in javascript at client. Can anybody help me to do this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json_decode()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: One note: to convert to an array rather than an object requires json_decode($json_string, true);

Answer (score 3):

From the top of my head, without knowing anything about your code

you could use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode)

use it like this:

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);

#check the second parameter set to true, otherwise you will get a stdclass.
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel.. I'll try this in my code. Actually I am maintaining a live updated table at client periodically updated inside webpage. I'll post the progress here soon after it works.

Comment: Glad helped you. If you feel the answer helped you enough please accept it :) Thanks

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. It worked. Can you post here a link which can give me reference of all existing php functions. A kind of function library, as the book for php I am reading is not in very depth. Even w3schools does not cover all.

Comment: well this might help you: http://bit.ly/iQDTkr also http://php.net is the resource you should always follow